# UI5 Tree Table why repeated nodes?

Tags: treeview, odata, sapui5

I am trying to bind OData to a Tree Table following the OData Samples in [sap.ui.table.TreeTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.TreeTable)

I have tried both with basic binding with setting `treeAnnotationProperties`in the xml and annotation binding (I have checked the `$metadata` query and it has the `sap:hierarchy-` etc).

However, both times I get repeated nodes like:

```
Id    | Title     | Hierarchy Level | ParentID 
----------------------------------------------------
1     | izparent  | 0               | 0
|--1  | izparent  | 0               | 0
|  |-- ...
|--2  | izchild   | 1               | 1
2     | izchild   | 1               | 1
```

where I get a Node with Id 1 which is expandable, and Node 2 which is not expandable. But if I expand Node 1, I again get Node 1 which is expandable and Node 2, and I can repeated expand Node 1 to get the same result.

I have a feeling I have a similar problem as here, but there is no answer provided for this either: [How to define tree table annotation (XML view)](https://answers.sap.com/questions/342383/how-to-define-tree-table-annotation-xml-view.html)

I am using OData Version 2.0 and for my `et_entity` I just provide a `SELECT * FROM` a table which has the structure I think I need according to the samples.

Table content:

```
Id | Title    | HierarchyLevel | ParentID | Drillstate
1    izparent   0                0          expanded
2    izchild    1                1          leaf
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that adding `operationMode: 'Client'` to the `rows` parameters solved the issue.

It appears that expanding triggers another Server call (additional `$batch` appears under debugging network tab), and therefore extra logic has to be included in the `GetEntitySet` method to handle expands on lower hierarchy levels, so it doesn't provide the full hierarchy anymore (e.g. `if hierarchy level = ..., then select only hierarchy level < ...`).
 Since the amount of data I am handling allows `operationMode: client`, I did not further the additional logic approach.

Comment: where to add operation mode property ?

Comment: @MudassirHasan From the [Basic OData TreeBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.ui.table.TreeTable/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.BasicODataTreeBinding) sample, in the view.xml file, you need to add a parameter to the rows:
`rows="{ path: '/Nodes', parameters : {  countMode: 'Inline', operationMode: 'Client', treeAnnotationProperties : { hierarchyLevelFor : 'HierarchyLevel', hierarchyNodeFor : 'NodeID', hierarchyParentNodeFor : 'ParentNodeID', hierarchyDrillStateFor : 'DrillState'} }  }"`